# Modify the MVC default behaviour of boolean types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I defined this editorTemplate to modify the behaviour of a boolean type, my problem is when the type is nullable I want to create a combo to change the default values, to what I want, but I don't know how to select the value that come's from the model.

For example if the value is `true` I want the dropdownlist selected with `SI` value and false with `NO`. Now, I know that I can get the value of the model like this `Model.Value` but i don't know how to pass to the seleclist depending of the model. Here's my editorTemplate

```
@model Nullable<bool>

@{
    var listItems = new[]{
        new SelectListItem { Value = "null", Text = "Sin Valor" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "true", Text = "Si" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "false", Text = "No"}
    };
}

@if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsNullableValueType)
{

    @Html.DropDownList("", listItems)
}
else
{
    @Html.CheckBox("", ViewData.Model.Value)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set this on the `SelectListItem`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

```
@model Nullable<bool>

@{
    var listItems = new[]{
        new SelectListItem { Value = "null", Text = "Sin Valor", Selected = !Model.HasValue },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "true", Text = "Si", Selected = Model.HasValue && Model.Value },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "false", Text = "No", Selected = Model.HasValue && !Model.Value}
    };
}

@if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsNullableValueType)
{

    @Html.DropDownList("", listItems)
}
else
{
    @Html.CheckBox("", ViewData.Model.Value)
}
```

Comment: I am thinking how would you ever reach the checkbox scenario?  Your editor template is for the nullable only type. I might be missing something here, though.